# Webpack failure: "ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat 'node_modules/.cache/hard-source/.DS_Store/stamp'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, webpack, react-slingshot

I have created a new project with [react-slingshot starter](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) and after running the webpack the second time I faced the following problem (persists):

1. The app cannot load in the browser, it keeps waiting for the response from the webpack dev server.
2. And in the terminal I see the error: `ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat 'node_modules/.cache/hard-source/.DS_Store/stamp'`.

I can fix it by deleting the `.DS_Store` file, but that helps only until the next code change. Basically, I have to restart the webpack (and delete the file) for every source code change, which is very slow and painful feedback.

I have tried to search for this problem and stumbled on [this issue](https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin/issues/456). I have applied the suggestion to exclude the `.DS_Store` using `HardSourceWebpackPlugin.ExcludeModulePlugin`:

```
plugins: [
    new HardSourceWebpackPlugin(),
    new HardSourceWebpackPlugin.ExcludeModulePlugin([
      {
        test: /.*\.DS_Store/
      }
    ]),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ...
],
```

But that didn't help—the problem persists.

Can you help me to somehow resolve this?

Comment: Do you still have this problem?